# bash replace array named after var with another array

Tags: bash

I have an array called NL and the variable arrayname='NL'.

I would like to set NL equal to the value of a second array (REPLACE_ARRAY) by using the arrayname variable.

Is this possible? I have read similar questions and do not see them address this, I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to find a resolution that worked for me!

```
declare -a $varname='(${REPLACE_ARRAY[@]})'
```